# How do I set Mail.app not to send the recipient names as they appear in my address book

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts

When I send mails to addresses from my address book, the recipients in the address bar are shown like `name <nick@domain.tld>`. Can I somehow prevent that name part, so that only the actual mail address is shown and not the names, as I name them in my personal address book? I kind of feel like it's not for the public how I name my contacts.

Answer (score 2):

While composing and email you can click the arrow in the address and choose *Edit Address* or double-click the address to edit the information. By deleting the name and leaving just the email address (it should look something like `< someone@somewhere.com >`) should do the trick. I couldn't find a way of having this changes done permanently, though.

Comment: There is no way to permanently disable this behavior, without switching to a mail client that doesn't do this. (Every modern mail client that I am aware of does so, though.)